# How to use power led from arduino-pro-micro?

Tags: arduino-pro-micro

In my project I need 3 leds. I would like to use on-board leds if possible.

I know how to use `PB0` and `PD5` red on-board leds, and I would like to hack the board somehow to use the green power led.

If I do not find a way to use the power led from MCU, I'm planning to destroy it anyway, because it is constantly on, which is harmful in my project.

Comment: refer to the schematic

Comment: The power led is connected directly to the 5V line. So you'd need to modify the board (cut a trace and add a tiny wire).

Answer (score 0):

There are 34-pin atmega32u4-based boards. They have 3 leds. So use them instead of pro-micro board.